# iron-ajax response returns null for php json response

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax, polymer-1.0

I'm a beginner in polymer 1.0 in the following codes I'm trying to get json response from my php file when the iron-ajax's on-response triggers. I have tried different response by editing php, but it always shows null in my console log. 
ajax part of the code

```
<iron-ajax
        id="ajax"
        method="POST"
        url="post_tip.php"
        handle-as="json"
        on-response="postResponse"
        >
    </iron-ajax>
```

script part of code to handle on-response

```
postResponse: function(r){
            console.log(r.detail.response);
            if(r.detail.response.success==1){
                console.log('Tip posted');
            }
            else{console.log('Error occured.not posted');}
        }
```

I can't find any error but `r.detail.response` returns null every time.

on my php I have.

```
$resp = '{"success":1}';
echo $resp;
echo json_encode($resp);
```

can't figure out which part I'm doing wrong. sorry for the possible dumb question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You doing it all wrong in php. First of all [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) will encode an array or an object to json string, it will escape your string, but thats not that what you want. Secondly you returning twice without `[ ]` bracket which cannot be parsed with [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) or cannot be used as a [`JSON Object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON) in javascript.

You should send back JSON `content-type`, because the response  may be not hooked trough [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse), and expecting a real [`JSON`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON), but on the iron-ajax documentation the [`handle-as="json"`](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-ajax#property-handleAs) means:

> json: uses XHR.responseText parsed as JSON.

So the `iron-ajax` element using [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) on the `XHR.responseText` to parse the [`JSON`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON) as an object, that means the PHP header is not required but you should use.

Change your php code something like this:

```
<?php

    $result = array('success' => 1);

    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($result);
```

Comment: thanks a lot man :) that really solved my issue and I have learned quite a bit from the answer.